# python/string: how to get all the possible combinations in string considering only space for splitting the string

Tags: python, string, combinations

I have a string
 `dt = '301 302 303'`
how can I get different combinations of above string with considering only spaces while splitting the string.

```
# output
301
302
303
301 302
301 303
302 303
301 302 303
```

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.combinations`

Comment: You can use `dt.split()` to get a list of the elements.

Comment: Well, yes, because you told it you only wanted combinations with length 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use itertools module
turn the string to a list
and then iterate

```
dt = '301 302 303' 
import itertools
list1 = dt.split()
for i in range(1,len(list1) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(list1,i):
        print(subset)
```

output

```
('301',)
('302',)
('303',)
('301', '302')
('301', '303')
('302', '303')
('301', '302', '303')
```